# Is there a way in TFS to see all the files that have been worked on by different users?

Tags: tfs, history

I have 3 people working on 1 Team project in TFS. I want to see all the users' work from the date when this Team project was branched until the day the last user checked in his work. It's required so I know how many files to transfer to another server.

Does anyone know if there is a way? I did "view history" and it didn't really give me what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself a copy (free) of the TFS Power Tools. It contains a great feature called Find In Source Control. This allows you to search for check-ins based on a number of criteria, including a range of dates, or a begin and end changeset number, and more.

Comment: power tools is outdated. i downloaded it from website, and they themselves say its outdated. Is there a different link you have?

Comment: For 2008 it appears to be: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=fbd14eea-781f-45a1-8c46-9f6ba2f68bf0

Answer (score 2):

Randy Minder's answer should meet your needs as stated in the question.  But, if you want to see the work represented in another way, you can compare your work to the server path from which it was branched.

1. From the View menu, choose Team Explorer.  Browse to the project your project and double-click on the "Source Control" node.  This opens your "Source Control Explorer".
2. In Source Code Explorer, right-click on on the folder where you've been working.  Choose "Compare" from the menu.  This will open a dialog that compares two server locations for differences.  By default, the folder you've just clicked on will be the Target Path of the comparison.
3. In the dialog, click on the Source Path Browse button and choose "Source Path".  Another dialog will appear, asking you to choose a path on the server.
4. Browse to and choose the server path from which you branched.

Visual Studio will now give you a comparison (recursive through folders) of the two paths, showing which files have changed and easily letting you inspect differences and histories of those files.

If the Source Path hasn't changed since you branched, and you've checked everything into the Target Path, the "Folder Difference" pane should represent the work you've done since you branched.

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I needed :)